# how to customize the list view in basis of dates

Tags: java, android, listview

I want to add customize list view in android.What i want is show a list of records on the basis of weeks.Like this week then some records.Last week then some records [image]

Comment: can you please post your code? what you have done so for to achieve it?

Comment: i have not done much. don't know how to do it

Comment: Use an `ExpandableListView`.

Comment: I don't want to use the ExpandableListView

Comment: Then use two item layouts. one for the title (Date) and the next for the row. Use switch case to identify the type of the data (title or row), and inflate the  corresponding layout in position

Comment: can you post some code or may be an example